Gitlab CI: save output files of each job at each stage
I have established CI (shell runner). I have a simple pipeline like this:
preprocessing_job1:
  tags:
    - block_autotest
  stage: preprocessing
  script:
    - <some calculations outputting some files to sandbox directory within repo>

preprocessing_job2:
  tags:
    - block_autotest
  stage: preprocessing
  script:
    - <other calculations outputting other files to sandbox directory within repo>

runtime_job1:
  tags:
    - block_autotest
  stage: runtime
  script:
    - <some more calculations outputting some more files to sandbox directory within repo>

runtime_job2:
  tags:
    - block_autotest
  stage: runtime
  script:
    - <new calculations outputting new files to sandbox directory within repo>

I have a "sandbox" directory within my repository where all the calculations are run. This folder is empty at the beginning of the pipeline. After a job finished this folder gets cleaned up by ci algorithms.
I have another empty folder called "results" within my repository. I want all the output files of all the jobs to be moved and saved at folder \results\job_name after pipeline finished so I can go there and see these files after the pipeline finished.

do oyu want them to be saved in artifacts or an external drive?

@nbk as far as I understand, artifacts are downloaded everytime a new job starts. My output files may be too large and I dont want them to be downloaded. So what I need is to move output files from sandbox folder to results folder after finishing a new job and I dont want gitlab to clean up results folder but to keep all the output files there

you can copy all accessible files from one folder to another as long the operating system has it mounted, with operating system commands like you would do it in a shell

but you could copy them also to nextcloud or google drive

@IzaeDA you can prevent following jobs from downloading artifacts: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#needsartifacts
